# ProGuard in Android Studio provide very weak obfuscation.

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

After applying proguard to my code it's still pretty readable. Classes and packages are not renamed.  Class variables, that is all that was renamed. 
Android Studio 2.2.3. 
build:gradle:2.2.3

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mypackagename"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.0"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}

 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dexOptions {
    dexInProcess = true
}

   lintOptions {
    abortOnError true
    checkReleaseBuilds true
}
}

ext {
supportLibVersion = '25.0.1'
playServisesVersion = '10.0.0'
}

repositories {
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.5'
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.0.0'
compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.0.1'
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:${playServisesVersion}"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:${playServisesVersion}"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:${playServisesVersion}"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${playServisesVersion}"
compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.34'
compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.5.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**proguard-rules.pro**

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in C:.....proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
-dontwarn com.github.mikephil.charting.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.graphics.drawable.** { *; }
```

**Viewing my release apk**
[image]

Comment: @Aenadon Yes. I did tried proguard-android-optimize.txt. My apk has become 30kb smaller, but no visible difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see that you are using the library `AppIntro`. This library has an issue, where the proguard rules of the library are preserving all classes in the project. The proguard rules of the library are merged with the local ones and so in the final build all classes are preserved and will not be obfuscated.

This issue has been fixed in 4.2, but this version has not been released on Maven Central. Meanwhile, you have to clone the library locally and import it manually in gradle.

**Steps:**

1. Download or clone the library locally via Github (there is a green `Clone or Download` Button)
2. Create a new folder `libs` in the root of your project
3. Create a new folder `AppIntro` in the `libs` folder
4. Place the contents of the `library`-folder of the cloned project in the `AppIntro` folder we created in step 3
5. Add `include ':libs:AppIntro'` to your `settings.gradle`
6. Replace `compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'` with `compile project(':libs:AppIntro')` in your `build.gradle`

Now proguard should work normally!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes indeed, after removing AppIntro library proguard started to work properly.

Comment: I have a same issue now, and I don't have this AppIntro library in my project. How to properly diagnose and find a bad apple who is causing ProGuard to exclude all the classes?